# django: ajax simple loading gif not working/ over-riding render to output page

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have a functioning upload function implemented in django. The files being handled are large making for a long waiting time and so I would like to provide a "Please Wait/ Loading.../ GIF" on the page while the files are loading.

The HTML/Django that begins the uploading function is as follows:

```
   <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" id="Upload" onclick = "showMessage()"/></p>
```

The upload button is as follows (accompanied by a hidden div):

```
     <div class="up" id="up" style="display:none;">
       <img src="{% static 'img/ajax-loader.gif' %}" alt="loading"/>
     </div>
```

I took some example code and tried to adapt it to the above HTML but it's not showing up on the page at all during the loading time... and I have no errors to follow.

The ajax:

```
<script>
function showMessage() {
$('.up').show()
// document.getElementById("up").innerHTML = "please wait";
}
</script>
```

However my ajax code is not having any effect as the hidden div does not appear after clicking "Upload".

I am not at all familiar with Ajax/javascript and so while I understand that I can see that I am able to set a function "showMessage" and then upon clicking "Upload" the function will be called should render the hidden div to the page until the output is complete and rendered to the output page.

I should also mention that before I decided to use a GIF I successfully managed to get a "Please wait" message to appear after clicking the "Upload" button (this code is silenced in the "showMessage" function above.

The problem is that the "Please Wait" message actually over-rides the rendering to the output page and hence the results of the upload do not display when processed.

Hence overall I just want a hidden div to render to the input page until the output is complete and in a way that will not conflict with the more important, subsequent rendering to the output page.

The syntax I'm using is not having any effect on the page so I'm hoping someone can correct my misguided code.

Thanks